# Error using fluidsynth

Tags: sound, python, alsa, jack

I installed fluidsynth following the instructions here:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fluidsynth/wiki/Download

...which were just `sudo apt-get install fluidsynth`

But get the following error when I try to run it and am unable to access it from python:

```
$ fluidsynth
FluidSynth version 1.1.5
Copyright (C) 2000-2011 Peter Hanappe and others.
Distributed under the LGPL license.
SoundFont(R) is a registered trademark of E-mu Systems, Inc.

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jackdmp 1.9.8
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2011 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
Cannot create thread 1 Operation not permitted
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Cannot lock down 82246176 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
control device hw:0
control device hw:0
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
control device hw:0
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
AcquireSelfRealTime error
Cannot lock down 82246176 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/5)(1: Operation not permitted)
JackClient::AcquireSelfRealTime error
Type 'help' for help topics.
```

Comment: Do you want fluidsynth to play through Jack or ALSA?

Comment: I just want it to make sounds quickly.  What's easier?  I guess I have both installed.

Comment: I see lots of permissions notices... you might need to run the command with `sudo`.

Comment: That's kind of a high permission level for a little ol' audio program, right?  Is there any better way?

Comment: Most of these messages, despite looking as errors, are not critical, and fluidsynth should work fine anyway. The point is that it is common to use the JACK audio server [as well as some other audio apps] using tricky modes (like realtime priority, memory locking) in order to achieve maximum performance. Such tricks require special priviledges, and therefore fluidsynth and JACK fail to use them, but none of them is required for fluidsynth to work, it should output sound nicely regardless of them.
If it won't, the problem is likely to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Real-time permission would allow Jack to configure itself for a higher scheduling priority, and to prevent its memory from swapping.
However, Jack also runs without these settings.

If you want just simple playback, you should configure fluidsynth to use ALSA.